# Can I put one django site inside of another?

Tags: django, django-sites

I started develop two sites separately, but now I need to merge them (so http://site1.com/site2) points to site2 (which has a separate settings.py).

I could probably refactor the code and make site2 an app of site1, but I suspect there is an easy way. Also, site2 uses a different database, and I don't intend to mix up both databases...

If I want to use subdomain (like site2.site1.com), will it make it easier?

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to leave both Django applications separate but present them as one site using a reverse proxy such as nginx.  The applications will live on separate servers or at least be served on the same server on separate ports, and nginx will proxy requests to one application or the other based on what path is requested.

Comment: Hi Andrew, If I want to use subdomain (like site2.site1.com), will it make it easier?

Comment: No, that's the same process.  The only difference is that you won't have to pay for registration of two domains.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I misunderstood what you were asking.  If you use subdomains INSTEAD OF trying to put them on the same directory tree, then yes, that is much easier.

Comment: In that case they can be totally different servers and you don't need a reverse proxy or any shared configuration or code refactoring.